# Stuck in an infinite loop? (Maybe)

Tags: c++, collatz

I am trying to complete Project Euler [Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14) in c++ and I am honestly stuck. Right now when I run the problem it gets stuck at So Far: the number with the highest count: 113370 with the count of 155
So Far: the number with the highest count but when I try changing the i value to over 113371 it works. What is going on??

The question is:

> The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive
>   integers:  n → n/2 (n is even) n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
>
> Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following
>   sequence:
>
> 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1    It can be seen that this
>   sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 10 terms.
>   Although it      has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem), it is
>   thought that all starting numbers finish at 1. Which starting number,
>   under one million, produces the longest chain?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int limit = 1000000;
    int highNum, number, i;
    int highCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for( number = 13; number <= 1000000; number++ )
    {
        i = number;
        while( i != 1 ) {
            if (( i % 2 ) != 0 ) {
                i = ( i * 3 ) + 1;
                count++;
            }
            else {
                count++;
                i /= 2;
            }
        }
        count++;
        printf( "So Far: the number with the highest count: %d with the count of %d\n",
                     number, count );
        if( highCount < count ) {
            highCount = count;
            highNum = number;
        }
        count = 0;
        //break;
    }
    printf( "The number with the highest count: %d with the count of %d\n",
            highNum, highCount );
}
```

Comment: If the program works correctly for relatively small numbers, but "gets stuck in an infinite loop" for large numbers, it's likely not an infinite loop, your algorithm is just slow.

Comment: Your problem is that you are recomputing the same partial results over and over.

Comment: check the limits of data types you are using, use unsigned long int

Comment: Look up the concept of [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). :)

Comment: @Nadosh it's only a `1000000` it's not ever the 2.1 cap

Comment: @PictureMeAndYou: Your limit is 1000000 but as you compute the length of each sequence some _intermediate_ values will exceed the range of a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: I can't help but wonder what would happen if you computed all chains starting from zero going in the opposite direction: `{1}, {2}, {4}, {8}, {16}, {32, 5}, {64, 10}, ...` and keeping track of which elements in 0-1000000 have not yet been reached, would that be faster or slower than the "obvious" algorithm mentioned by everyone else?  No need of memoization then, or any sort of history.  I don't know if it's more or less memory, the number of elements in each pass would grow exponentially.

Comment: Actually, along that same line of thought, in the obvious strategy, you can immediately discard every number between 1-500000 as the longest chain, because the value double that is always going to have a chain one longer.  You can also discard all numbers where `(N-1)%3==0`.  That cuts the number of possibilities down by 66% right there.

Comment: Wait, my strategy will fail, because at a chain of 64, it tries to store a temporary that overflows a 64bit value.

Comment: I tested it, even if you discard large temporaries, my idea is absurdly slow.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Starting at 500000 is really bad for the branch-predictor. I tested it with my linked variant doing less memoization.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting integer overflow. Update your code like this and see it yourself:

```
if (( i % 2 ) != 0 ) {
    int prevI = i;
    i = ( i * 3 ) + 1;
    if (i < prevI) {
        printf("oops, i < prevI: %d\n", i);
        return 0;
    }
    count++;
}
```

You should change the type of `i` to `long long` or `unsigned long long` to prevent the overflow.

<sup>(And yes, cache the intermediate results)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Remember all intermediate results (up to some suitably high number).
Also, use a big-enough type:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int collatz[4000000];
unsigned long long collatzmax;

int comp(unsigned long long i) {
  if(i>=sizeof collatz/sizeof*collatz) {
      if(i>collatzmax)
        collatzmax = i;
      return 1 + comp(i&1 ? 3*i+1 : i/2);
  }
  if(!collatz[i])
      collatz[i] = 1 + comp(i&1 ? 3*i+1 : i/2);
  return collatz[i];
}

int main() {
  collatz[1] = 1;
  int highNumber= 1, highCount = 1, c;
  for(int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++)
    if((c = comp(i)) > highCount) {
      highCount = c;
      highNumber = i;
    }
  printf( "The number with the highest count: %d with the count of %d\n",
        highNumber, highCount );
  printf( "Highest intermediary number: %llu\n", collatzmax);
}
```

On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/773bd8c5f4e7d5a9

Variant with smaller runtime: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2132cb74e4605d5f

```
The number with the highest count: 837799 with the count of 525
Highest intermediary number: 56991483520
```

BTW: The highest intermediary encountered needs 36 bit to represent as an unsigned number.

Comment: @Jarod42: The correct magic number is a bit too high. Added code to calculate it.

Comment: **+1** I think, you need to iterate only over odd numbers.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: I'm not convinced that's a valid optimization (though I determined several that are valid along similar reasoning)

Comment: @PetrBudnik: You only need to iterate two out of every three numbers 500000-1000000 though: where `N%3==1` is false.  In the end I bet it's about the same since most of the rest get memoized anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With your algorithm, you compute several time identical series.
you may cache result for previous numbers and reuse them.

Something like:

```
void compute(std::map<std::uint64_t, int>& counts, std::uint64_t i)
{
    std::vector<std::uint64_t> series;
    while (counts[i] == 0) {
        series.push_back(i);
        if ((i % 2) != 0) {
            i = (i * 3) + 1;
        } else {
            i /= 2;
        }
    }
    int count = counts[i];
    for (auto it = series.rbegin(); it != series.rend(); ++it)
    {
        counts[*it] = ++count;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::uint64_t limit = 1000000;

    std::map<std::uint64_t, int> counts;
    counts[1] = 1;
    for (std::size_t i = 2; i != limit; ++i) {
        compute(counts, i);
    }
    auto it = std::max_element(counts.begin(), counts.end(),
        [](const std::pair<std::uint64_t, int>& lhs, const std::pair<std::uint64_t, int>& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.second < rhs.second;
        });
    std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << std::endl;
    std::cout << limit-1 << ":" << counts[limit-1] << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffd8907dc902023d) (10 seconds)

Comment: The weird thing is it is stopping at the exact same spot

Comment: @PictureMeAndYou: With provided code, I get a result in 10 seconds.

Comment: @Jarod42: It can be [done in 0.034 seconds](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cb66825754e3f78).

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Why a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` as opposed to a `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: In retrospect, I think I wanted to avoid value initializing the container and it was less typing than `reserve/push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't recompute the same intermediate results over and over!

Given

```
typedef std::uint64_t num;  // largest reliable built-in unsigned integer type

num collatz(num x)
{
    return (x & 1) ? (3*x + 1) : (x/2);
}
```

Then the value of `collatz(x)` only depends on `x`, not on when you call it. (In other words, `collatz` is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).) As a consequence, you can [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the values of `collatz(x)` for different values of `x`. For this purpose, you could use a `std::map<num, num>` or a `std::unordered_map<num, num>`.

For reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20558092/46571) is the complete solution.

And here it is on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fba80660fb9e9f57), with timing (2.6 secs).

Comment: Yes I know there are faster ways to do this, but I want to try my way because it was original for me and understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @PictureMeAndYou: Your way does not work *precisely* because your algorithm is too slow.

Comment: AFAIK, I thought it just takes a while to compile and run I never knew it would completely stop?

Comment: @PictureMeAndYou: If you write a program that would take a thousand years to complete running, for all practical intents and purposes, your program will never stop.

Comment: @EduardoLeón: His code only takes ~3.7 seconds on my machine once I change everything to `long long`.